# Google App Script check if the edited cell contains space

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following code is not working when I put a value with space in editedCellValue

```js
function onEdit(e) {

    var editedCellRange = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test").getActiveRange();
    var editedCellValue = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test").getActiveRange().getValue;
    if (RegExp(editedCellValue).test("\s")==true){editedCellRange.setValue("contains space")}
    else 
    {editedCellRange.setValue("ELSE IF")}
}
```

Please help with why this is not working.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- If you want to use `test`, please modify to `(/\s/g).test(editedCellValue)`.
- For example, you can also use `includes` like `editedCellValue.includes(" ")`. And also, `indexOf` can be used.
- In your situation, I think that the event object can be also used.
- In your script, `var editedCellValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test").getActiveRange().getValue;` doesn't retrieve the value because `getValue` is not run. Please add `()` like `getValue()`.
- You can declare one `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test")`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName().toLowerCase() != "test") return;
  var editedCellValue = range.getValue();
  if ((/\s/g).test(editedCellValue)) {  // or if (editedCellValue.includes(" ")) {
    range.setValue("contains space")
  } else {
    range.setValue("ELSE IF")
  }
}
```

- In this case, when you edit the cell, `onEdit` is automatically run by the OnEdit trigger. And, in your script, the edited cell is overwritten. Please be careful this.

#### Note:

- If you want to directly run the function with the script editor, please modify above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var range = e.range;
      if (range.getSheet().getSheetName().toLowerCase() != "test") return;
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test").getActiveRange();
    ```

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Thanks! (/\s/g).test(editedCellValue) is working.

Comment: @user13854773 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Now, I thought that in your situation, `(/\s/).test(editedCellValue)` can be also used.

Comment: Also appreciate the tip to clean up the code by not repeating myself.